# How to get the selected checkbox in matrix-table in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have designed a matrix table using html in angular as in the link:

```
<h1>Responsive table of input-checkbox-matrix type</h1>
<h3>Permissions Table</h3>
<table class="responsive-table-input-matrix">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Owner</th>
        <th>Administrators</th>
        <th>Managers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>Add</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Delete</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I need set the id for each column and rows in the table and if user clicks the checkbox which is in edit permission for manager, i need that values to store in array. Likewise finally i need a array of values which are all selected in the single row e.g. edit.

How to do this? Anyone can help?
And also how to achieve  in *ngFor here? In this it is hardcoded. But i need that to be in dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you wanted to get selected checkbox array in angluarjs right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .ts file make an array of objects

```
hasAdd = [
  {value: 'Owner', checked: false},
  {value: 'Admin', checked: false},
  {value: 'Manager', checked: false}
];
hasEdit = [
  {value: 'Owner', checked: false},
  {value: 'Admin', checked: false},
  {value: 'Manager', checked: false}
];
hasDelete = [
  {value: 'Owner', checked: false},
  {value: 'Admin', checked: false},
  {value: 'Manager', checked: false}
];
```

Now in your template,

```
<tr>
    <td>Add</td>
    <td *ngFor="let a of hasAdd">
      <input name="hasAdd" [(ngModel)]="a.checked" type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td *ngFor="let e of hasEdit">
      <input name="hasEdit" [(ngModel)]="e.checked" type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Delete</td>
    <td *ngFor="let d of hasDelete">
      <input name="hasDelete" [(ngModel)]="d.checked" type="checkbox">
    </td>
</tr>
```

To get the selected options you can pass each of the object arrays to this function.

```
selectedOptions(myarray) { 
return myarray
          .filter(opt => opt.checked)
          .map(opt => opt.value)
 }
```